# How to undo erasing when erase a bitmap on canvas?

Tags: android

I am working a project in which an erasing functionality is there I want to user can undo
    his erasing if he want but this functionality is not working for me.
                                                                       My code is as:-
[image]

```
public EraserView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
    // setting paint
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint.setAlpha(0);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    // getting image from resources
    Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.image2);

    // converting image bitmap into mutable bitmap

    bitmap = bm.createBitmap(295, 260, Config.ARGB_8888);
    pcanvas = new Canvas();
    pcanvas.setBitmap(bitmap); // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
    pcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
    paths.add(mPath);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // draw a circle that is erasing bitmap

    pcanvas.drawCircle(x,y,r,mPaint);
    /*for (Path objpath : paths) {
        pcanvas.drawPath(objpath, mPaint);
    }*/
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

    setBitmap(bitmap);
    super.onDraw(canvas);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        r = 8;
        // Atlast invalidate canvas
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        r = 8;
        // Atlast invalidate canvas
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        r = 8;
        // Atlast invalidate canvas
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        r = 8;
        // Atlast invalidate canvas
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

public void onClickUndo () { 
    if (paths.size()>0) 
    { 
       paths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
       invalidate();
     }
    else
    {

    }
}![enter image description here][1]
```

as shown in image we erase some part of dog after that click undo button dog should come in his initial position.please any one guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving `(Canvas.save())` the Canvas before erasing any portion of the bitmap and then restoring `(Canvas.restore())` and redrawing once the button is clicked?

Comment: canvas save() and restore() only save or restore it's state not drawing on canvas. I mean it will save rotation transformation etc but it will not save/restore any drawing.

@SKT : you can save more then one state using multiple time calling save().. and undo those using restore() calling multiple times.

for undo / redo drawing please check following demo. it may help.
https://github.com/hardik-trivedi/PaintApp